# How do I completely turn off cookies in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok guys, need to turn off the cookies in my ASP.net site *completely*

I'm doing some funky stuff serving images and scripts from a .aspx file, which causes the request to have cookies tagged to it.

So, how do I get rid of these?

I've tried setting the SessionState mode="Off" in the web.config, but that didn't seem to work.

Cheers, Ed

Comment: Just curious, what problem are the cookies causing?

Comment: Check this out to see if it helps: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free

Comment: @Lazarus none at all: I just want to max out the PageSpeed and YSlow rankings for the site. @Ricardo yeah, though that might be the case, I'm actually running it in my local VS environment at the moment so in theory there shouldn't BE any cookies with session off, but apparently not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client (browser) holds cookies for the domain, or any parent domain then it will send them on each HTTP request.

E.g. `images.acme.com` will get any cookies set by `acme.com`.

(Just like `acme.com/foo/` cookies will be sent to `acme.com/foo/bar/`.)

If you want an images/static site to not get cookies from the application site then you need to use a domain that is not a child of the main site. (This is why SO serves static content from `http://sstatic.net/` rather than a child domain of `http://stackoverflow.com`.

All of this is inherent in the way cookies are defined.

Comment: This is a static site, so I don't want to send cookies at all from the main site: I was wondering if it is possible to disable them from inside ASP.net, however the lack of responses seems to indicate that this is not possible.

Comment: @EdWoodcock: I think you will need to work through what generates each cookie... start by ensuring none of the ASP.NET providers are available (`<clear/>` in each list in the web.config).

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the solution in your question, Ed, but maybe forgot to clear previous set cookies?

I created a new simple MVC site, and by default it used a session cookie. However, I wanted a cookiefree site so I removed the session cookie as you tried:

Set <sessionState mode="Off"> in the web.config under the <system.web> element.

Remember, when you have added this to your config you need to CLEAR all cookies in you browser and then reload you page. You should then see that no cookies are present by for example studying the response using Chrome development tools (Resources -> Cookies -> Localhost).